# Extending the Groovy MarkupTemplateEngine with Mixin classes

Tags: templates, groovy

I am using the Groovy MarkupTemplateEngine to generate some xhtml

I would like to have a library of extension classes that can be mixed into the BaseTemplate class on demand. For example a utility class

```
class FormField {

    static void textField(String title, String content) {

        div(class: 'form-field') {
            div(title, class: 'form-field-label')
            div(content, class: 'form-field-content')
        }

    }


    static void checkboxField(String title, boolean state) {

        String suffix = state ? 'checked' : 'unchecked';
        String src = 'img/common/checkbox_' + suffix + '.svg';


        img(src: src, class: 'checkbox-image')
        span(title, class: 'form-field-label')
    }
}
```

That provide some higher level constructs, that you can mixin into your template if you need them

I know that you could add these method to a custom base template class, but then you would potentially add many methods to a single class and you would not have IDE autocompletion support.

Here's what I have been trying:

```
abstract class ExtendedBaseTemplate extends BaseTemplate {


    ExtendedBaseTemplate(MarkupTemplateEngine templateEngine,
                         Map model, Map<String, String> modelTypes,
                         TemplateConfiguration configuration) {

        super(templateEngine, model, modelTypes, configuration)
    }


    // single extension method
    void f0() {
        p('hi from f0()')
    }
}
```

And some test template

```
assert GroovySystem.version == '2.5.7'
assert this instanceof BaseTemplate
assert this.class.getSimpleName().startsWith('GeneratedMarkupTemplate')


def f1() {
    p('hi from f1()')
}
assert this.metaClass.methods*.name.contains('f1')


// add a new method via metaClass
this.metaClass.f2 = {
    p('hi from f2()')
}
// seems to have worked
assert this.metaClass.methods*.name.contains('f2')


// TODO mixin some required utility classes here 


html {
    body {
        h1('Test')


        // ok renders as <p>`hi from f0()`</p>
        f0()

        // ok rendered as <p>hi from f1()</p>
        f1()

        // What? rendered as <p>hi from f2()</p>
        p(f2())

        // What? rendered as <f2/> -> method missing
        f2()
    }
}
```

I was not even able to add an additional method (f2()) via the template metaClass. Even though it seems to be available on the template it does not work as expected

Comment: what if `this.metaClass.f2 = {
   delegate.p('hi from f2()')
}`

Comment: @daggett: Does not work `p(f2())` results in `NullPointerException` and `f2()` still renders as `<f2/>`

Comment: `this.model.f2 = { ... }` must work

Comment: It does work indeed. However attaching the methods to the user data model map seems a bit odd. And I still dont get it why f1() works fine and f2() does not even though both methods appear in the metaClass.methods list